# C# remove SQL from method and use stored procedure & Dapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, dapper

I'm trying to convert a method to use a stored procedure with Dapper. But I'm quite confused with what's going on with `var result =...`

```
public Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(Guid userId)
{
    var sql = @"SELECT *
                FROM IdentityUser
                WHERE UserId = @USERID";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connection))
    {
        var result = connection.Query<TUser, IdentityProfile, TUser>(sql, (user, profile) => { user.Profile = profile;
                             return user; }, 
                          new { userId }, splitOn: "UserId").SingleOrDefault();

        return Task.FromResult(result);
     }
}
```

Here is what I have:

```
public Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(Guid userId)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connection))
    {
        var param = new DynamicParameters();
        param.Add("@UserId", userId);

        return Task.FromResult(connection.Query("IdentityGetUserById", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault());
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a problem? what is it?

Answer (score 2):

> But I'm quite confused with what's going on with var result =...

Needn't be confused this is simple **Dapper** functionality

Let me explain what the following code does:

```
var result = connection.Query<TUser, IdentityProfile, TUser>
                        (sql, (user, profile) => 
                        { 
                             user.Profile = profile;
                             return user; 
                        }, new { userId }, 
                       splitOn: "UserId").SingleOrDefault();
```

1. User is a complex type with Profile type part of it
2. Result on executing the Sql query is a combined tabulated data (with columns for both, User and Profile), which is automatically split at the column `UserId` and then it represent the Profile type, which is filled in the User type, as per logic `user.Profile = profile`
3. Since query results in `IEnumerable<TUser>`, therefore `SingleOrDefault` is called, which returns data if `Single record` is returned or returns `null`
4. This is a standard mechanism to automatically bind `complex types`

Now same kind of code is expected when you run the stored procedure, `IdentityGetUserById`, only changes are replace real Sql by stored procedure name (done), tell Dapper that you are executing stored procedure (done), you have already bind the parameters using `DynamicParameter`, which can also be anonymous type. Result will be in a similar format and you can do exactly same binding, check the following code, with few modifications:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connection))
{
        var result = connection.Query<TUser, IdentityProfile, TUser>
        ("IdentityGetUserById", 
         commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure,
         (user, profile) => 
                        { 
                           user.Profile = profile;
                           return user; 
                        }, new { userId }, 
                       splitOn: "UserId").SingleOrDefault();

          return Task.FromResult(result);
         );
}
```

In fact, I have removed `Dynamic Parameters` and used the `Anonymous type` to ensure that it is consistent with the Sql code